# Fitting a webpage to all resolutions

Tags: html, css, web-services

I was searching about how to make your webpage fits any screen resolution and I found that most answers prefer using % over Pixels. I found that this is correct when I viewed the code of this website http://zcsfestival.com/ 
you can find objects overlap in mobile resolution or when you don't maximize the window of your browser. However, when I read the code of this site http://m3adikawmia.eb2a.com/?ckattempt=1
I found that it uses Pixels and it fits any screen resolution also when I restore the browser window down. It seems perfect. I became confused about that and I want any clarification about this point.

Thanks in advnace,

Comment: It sounds like you want to read up on media queries http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp They essentially allow you to apply different styles depending on certain criteria such as screen width. If the screen width (in this example) changes and crosses a media query boundary, the css in another media query will kick in.

Comment: can you try responsive frameworks.Bootstrap or Polymer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to define elements with % . But some times the elements will be to small in mobile resolution that it is necessary to define different CSS codes for different resolutions. Like this:

normal situation:

```
.container {width: 1000px;}
```

responsive:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    /* redefining some element sizes like the example: */
    .container {width:100%;}
}
```

And this way will continue till mobile resolution.